# Install Flash player 10.0.x after 10.1

Tags: flash, flash-player

I had the Flash palyer 10.1 installed for testing purpose. Now I want to go back to 10.0.x. I deinstalled 10.1 and started the offline installer of 10.0.x. The installer prompts with an error that this version is outdated and that I should install the newest version. Unplugging the net cable didn't work either so I am looking for some hint where the Flash player stores some info AFTER deinstallation ...

Comment: How did you... uh "deinstall" Flash?

Comment: Via the deinstaller under "Software"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overcome the issue regarding the check for newer version there exists developer installs of the Flash player. These do not check for newer versions. They can be found under http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14266.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Install [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/) to your machine. (30-day fully functional free trial)
2. Reinstall Flash Player 10.1.
3. Open Revo Uninstaller, find Flash Player 10.1, right click and select "Uninstall".
4. Select "Advanced" option in the uninstallation window.
5. After the program is uninstalled, Revo will find the remainings of registry entries, files and folders. Delete them all.
6. You're done with v10.1 now. Retry to install v10.0.x.

Comment: I am sorry, no success :/